# How can I Increase swap partiton by decreasing root partion and be able to hibernate my system

Tags: partitioning, swap, hibernate

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,
- Platform: 64bit,
- Root partition(/) size: 153.6 GB,
- Free space in root partition(/): 140.2 GB,
- Swap partition size: 6 gb,
- Any free/Unallocated space in disk: No,
- Dual Boot/Other OS: Yes, Windows 10,
- Main objective: To be able to hibernate ubuntu

I tried to hibernate my system but it failed. I read in some articles that I must allocate swap space equal to the size of RAM installed on my system to perform hibernate. I have no space left in my hard disk other than Ubuntu root partition so how can I shrink it and add 2 GB to swap to make it 8 GB.

Will it hibernate then? Is there any other way?

Comment: This might help, https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation/Hibernate_Without_Swap_Partition

Comment: No my question is different Please read it again. BTW the answer by Ravexina solved my problem :)

Comment: The linked question answers your question “how can I shrink [the Ubuntu root partition] and add 2 GB to swap to make it 8 GB?”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to add a swap file instead of resizing root partition.

First create a empty file somewhere in `/`

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024K count=2000
```

make it a swap file:

```
mkswap /swapfile
```

open `/etc/fstab`:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

add this line into it:

```
/swapfile         swap          swap    defaults        0 0
```

run:

```
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

check you swap size:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i swaptotal
7874913
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Will I be able to hibernate my system then?

Comment: I don't know if your problem is really related to the swap size, you can test it, if it didn't work you can easily. remove the file and specific line from `/etc/fstab`